# SQL - Left outer join doesn't seem to do the trick

Tags: sql, sqlite

Below is the SQL-Statement I'm talking about.
I have two tables. One contains all player, with it's unique id. The second table can contain multiple records per player. Each record holds some kind of score, the "highest break". This can vary between 0 and 147.

Now what I want, is a SQL that always gives me all players selected in "p._id IN ()" with either the count of the records found with a score of 147, or null, if no records were found.

But this SQL will give me a resultset with 0 records. But it should give me a resultset with 3 records, each with a null-value for "breaks".

What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT p._id player, COUNT(fp.highest_break) breaks 
FROM player p LEFT OUTER JOIN frame_pos fp ON p._id = fp.player_id 
WHERE fp.highest_break = 147 
AND p._id IN (3,1,2) 
GROUP BY p._id ORDER BY breaks DESC
```

Btw.: It's an SQLite Database.

Comment: The description is unclear. Show example data, and the desired output.

Comment: What is unclear? Since the database lays on my phone, and it's not rooted, I can't even easily provide example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p._id player, COUNT(fp.highest_break) breaks 
FROM player p LEFT OUTER JOIN frame_pos fp ON p._id = fp.player_id 
AND fp.highest_break = 147 
WHERE p._id IN (3,1,2) 
GROUP BY p._id ORDER BY breaks DESC
```

Moving `fp.highest_break = 147` on the JOIN condition instead of WHERE allows rows in `fp` to be null...

Comment: But this is original query ... where is the answer ?!!

Comment: It is not original query. Clause `fp.highest_break = 147` is transposed.

Comment: You just switched the words "WHERE" and "AND"? I think thats not what you meant to do?

Comment: Yes, it is. Can you try it with your data?

Comment: Oh. Now I see what you did. You moved it into the join condition. Never did something like this, but it works. Thanks :)